# Real-Time Price Quote Calculator Javascript

Tags: javascript, calculator, quote

I'm having trouble with my price quote calculator, it just doesn't work and I have tried researching why and changing up the code and re-starting before uploading this.

My questions
Can anybody find the fault in my code to make this work?

Javascript:

```
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];

            var additionalLogo= new Array();
            additionalLogo["graphicNone"]=0;
            additionalLogo["graphicOne"]=10;
            additionalLogo["graphicTwo"]=20;
            additionalLogo["graphicThree"]=30;
            additionalLogo["graphicFour"]=40;
            additionalLogo["graphicFive"]=50;
            additionalLogo["graphicSix"]=60;
            additionalLogo["graphicSeven"]=70;
            additionalLogo["graphicEight"]=80;
            additionalLogo["graphicNine"]=90;
            additionalLogo["graphicTen"]=100;

            var additionalEmail= new Array();
            additionalEmail["webNone"]=0;
            additionalEmail["webOne"]=10;
            additionalEmail["webTwo"]=20;
            additionalEmail["webThree"]=30;
            additionalEmail["webFour"]=40;
            additionalEmail["webFive"]=50;
            additionalEmail["webSix"]=60;
            additionalEmail["webSeven"]=70;
            additionalEmail["webEight"]=80;
            additionalEmail["webNine"]=90;
            additionalEmail["webTen"]=100;

            function getGraphicBasePrice()
            {
                var graphicBasePrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var graphics = theQuoteForm.elements["graphics"];

                if(graphics.checked==true)
                {
                    graphicBasePrice=100;
                }
                else if(graphics.checked==false)
                {
                    graphicBasePrice=0;
                }

                return graphicBasePrice;
            }

            function sLogosPrice()
            {
                var sLogoPrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var smallLogo = theQuoteForm.elements["sLogo"];

                if(smallLogo.checked==true)
                {
                    sLogoPrice=20;
                }
                else if(smallLogo.checked==false)
                {
                    sLogoPrice=0;
                }

                return sLogoPrice;
            }

            function mLogosPrice()
            {
                var mLogoPrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var mediumLogo = theQuoteForm.elements["mLogo"];

                if(mediumLogo.checked==true)
                {
                    mLogoPrice=40;
                }
            else if(mediumLogo.checked==false)
                {
                    mLogoPrice=0;
                }

                return mLogoPrice;
            }

            function lLogosPrice()
            {
                var lLogoPrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var largeLogo = theQuoteForm.elements["lLogo"];

                if(largeLogo.checked==true)
                {
                    lLogoPrice=60;
                }
                else if(largeLogo.checked==false)
                {
                    lLogoPrice=0;
                }

                return lLogoPrice;
            }

            function getAdditionalLogoPrice()
            {
                var additionalLogoPrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var selectedAdditionalLogo = theQuoteForm.elements["additLogo"];

                additionalLogoPrice = additionalLogo[selectedAdditionalLogo.value];

                return additionalLogoPrice;
            }

            function postersPrice()
            {
                var posterPrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var Poster = theQuoteForm.elements["poster"];

                if(Poster.checked==true)
                {
                    posterPrice=60;
                }

                return posterPrice;
            }

            function illustrativesPrice()
            {
                var illustrativePrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var Illustrative = theQuoteForm.elements["illustrative"];

                if(Illustrative.checked==true)
                {
                    illustrativePrice=60;
                }

                return illustrativePrice;
            }

            function getWebBasePrice()
                            {
                var webBasePrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var web = theQuoteForm.elements["web"];

                if(web.checked==true)
                {
                    webBasePrice=150;
                }

                return webBasePrice;
            }

            function designsPrice()
                            {
                var designPrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var Design = theQuoteForm.elements["design"];

                if(Design.checked==true)
                {
                    designPrice=60;
                }

                return designPrice;
            }

            function developsPrice()
            {
                var developPrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var Develop =               theQuoteForm.elements["develop"];

                if(Develop.checked==true)
                {
                    developPrice=60;
                }

                return developPrice;
            }

            function seosPrice()
            {
                var seoPrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var Seo = theQuoteForm.elements["seo"];

                if(Seo.checked==true)
                {
                    seoPrice=60;
                }

                return seoPrice;
            }

            function cmssPrice()
            {
                var cmsPrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var Cms = theQuoteForm.elements["cms"];

                if(Cms.checked==true)
                                {
                            cmsPrice=60;
                }

                return cmsPrice;
            }

                            function hostingsPrice()
                            {
                var hostingPrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var Hosting = theQuoteForm.elements["hosting"];

                if(Hosting.checked==true)
                {
                    hostingPrice=60;
                }

                return hostingPrice;
            }

            function emailsPrice()
            {
                var emailPrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var emailAccount =              theQuoteForm.elements["emailAccount"];

                if(emailAccount.checked==true)
                {
                    emailPrice=60;
                }

                return emailPrice;
            }

            function getAdditionalEmailPrice()
            {
                var additionalEmailPrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var selectedAdditionalEmail =               theQuoteForm.elements["additEmail"];

                additionalEmailPrice =              additionalEmail[selectedAdditionalEmail.value];

                return additionalEmailPrice;
            }

            function maintenancesPrice()
            {
                var maintenancePrice=0;
                var theQuoteForm = document.forms["quoteForm"];
                var maintenance =               theQuoteForm.elements["maintenance"];

                if(maintenance.checked==true)
                {
                    maintenancePrice=60;
                }

                return maintenancePrice;
            }

            function calculateTotal()
            {
                var quoteFormPrice = getGraphicBasePrice() +                sLogosPrice() + mLogosPrice() + lLogosPrice() + getAdditionalLogoPrice() + postersPrice() + illustrativesPrice() + getWebBasePrice() + designsPrice() + developsPrice() + seosPrice() + cmssPrice() + hostingsPrice() + emailsPrice() + getAdditionalEmailPrice() + maintenancesPrice();

                var calculateObject = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
                calculateObject.innerHTML = "<b>Total Quote Price:</b> &pound;"+quoteFormPrice;
            }
```

HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="external/scripts/quoteCalculator.js"></script>


            <form action="" id="quoteForm" onsubmit="return false;" style="width: 630px; margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 20px; background-color: #fff; color: #000;">
                <fieldset style="width: 600px;">
                    <label for="graphics" class="graphicsLbl">Graphics</label>
                        <input id="graphics" class="checkBox" name="graphics" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=1><br /><br />

                    <label for="sLogo" class="Lbl">Small Logo (150px to 225px)</label>
                        <input id="sLogo" class="checkBox" name="sLogo" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=2><br /><br />

                    <label for="mLogo" class="Lbl">Medium Logo (226px to 360px)</label>
                        <input id="mLogo" class="checkBox" name="mLogo" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=3><br /><br />

                    <label for="lLogo" class="Lbl">Large Logo (361px+)</label>
                        <input id="lLogo" class="checkBox" name="lLogo" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=4><br /><br />

                    <label for="aLogo" class="additLogoLbl">Would you like additional logos?</label>
                        <input id="aLogo" class="checkBox" name="aLogo" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=5><br /><br />

                    <label for="additLogo" class="additLogoLbl">Choose amount of additional logos you would like:</label>
                        <select name="additLogo" id="additLogo" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #000" onchange="calculateTotal()" tabindex=6>
                            <option value="graphicNone">0</option>
                            <option value="graphicOne">1</option>
                            <option value="graphicTwo">2</option>
                            <option value="graphicThree">3</option>
                            <option value="graphicFour">4</option>
                            <option value="graphicFive">5</option>
                            <option value="graphicSix">6</option>
                            <option value="graphicSeven">7</option>
                            <option value="graphicEight">8</option>
                            <option value="graphicNine">9</option>
                            <option value="graphicTen">10</option>
                        </select><br /><br />

                    <label for="poster" class="Lbl">Poster</label>
                        <input id="poster" class="checkBox" name="poster" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=7><br /><br />

                    <label for="illustrative" class="Lbl">Illustrative</label>
                        <input id="illustrative" class="checkBox" name="illustrative" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=8><br /><br />

                    <label for="web" class="webLbl">Web</label>
                        <input id="web" class="checkBox" name="web" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=9><br /><br />

                    <label for="design" class="Lbl">Just design the look (Design)</label>
                        <input id="design" class="checkBox" name="design" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=10><br /><br />

                    <label for="develop" class="Lbl">We have a design to implement (Develop)</label>
                        <input id="develop" class="checkBox" name="develop" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=11><br /><br />

                    <label for="seo" class="Lbl">Search Engine Optimization (SEO)</label>
                        <input id="seo" class="checkBox" name="seo" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=12><br /><br />

                    <label for="cms" class="Lbl">Content Management Systems (CMS)</label>
                        <input id="cms" class="checkBox" name="cms" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=13><br /><br />

                    <label for="hosting" class="Lbl">We want the/a Website hosted (Hosting)</label>
                        <input id="hosting" class="checkBox" name="hosting" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=14><br /><br />

                    <label for="emailAccount" class="emailAccountLbl">Email Account Creation (Only with hosting)</label>
                        <input id="emailAccount" class="checkBox" name="emailAccount" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=15><br /><br />

                    <label for="aEmail" class="aEmailLbl">Would you like additional email accounts?</label>
                        <input id="aEmail" class="checkBox" name="aEmail" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=16><br /><br />

                    <label for="additEmailAccount" class="additEmailAccountLbl">Choose amount of additional email accounts you would like</label>
                        <select name="additEmailAccount" id="additEmailAccount" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #000" onchange="calculateTotal()" tabindex=17>
                            <option value="webNone">0</option>
                            <option value="webOne">1</option>
                            <option value="webTwo">2</option>
                            <option value="webThree">3</option>
                            <option value="webFour">4</option>
                            <option value="webFive">5</option>
                            <option value="webSix">6</option>
                            <option value="webSeven">7</option>
                            <option value="webEight">8</option>
                            <option value="webNine">9</option>
                            <option value="webTen">10</option>
                        </select><br /><br />

                    <label for="maintenance" class="Lbl">We would like you to maintain our Website (On-Going Maintenance)</label>
                        <input id="maintenance" class="checkBox" name="maintenance" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" tabindex=18><br /><br />
```

It all goes into this div:

```
                            <div id="totalPrice"></div>

                    </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: Do you have an error message? Check the browser console

Comment: The *Console* can be found in the *Developer Tools* (open via browser menu). All web developers should be aware of this tool.

Comment: No there isn't anything, it just doesn't work :s

Comment: @sBradfordsmith: "doesn't work" is a very broad statement. What doesn't work? What behavior is it supposed to be doing that it's not? What's it doing that it shouldn't? What function is not getting called when it should? Also, try putting your code in a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) so people can play around with it.

Comment: With the code you provide the console send me this error: selectedAdditionalEmail is undefined Assuming the js code is the quoteCalculator.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the function getAdditionalEmailPrice()

the name of the tag is incorrect.

only change this sentence

```
var emailAccount = theQuoteForm.elements["emailAccount"];
```

for this

```
var selectedAdditionalEmail = theQuoteForm.elements["additEmailAccount"];
```

and works.